# Javascript: Object method vs Object.prototype method

Tags: javascript

I'm studying the difference between Object.method and Object.prototype.method.
I know I should use Object.keys() as following.

```js
    var arr = new Array(1,2,3);
    console.log(Object.keys(arr)); //["0", "1", "2"]
```

and Object.prototype.toString() as following

```js
var arr = new Array(1,2,3);
arr.toString(); // "1,2,3"
console.log(arr.keys(arr));
```

I get

```
Array Iterator {}
```

at a console. Why? Shouldn't it be denied in the first place? (Since .keys() method is in Object object itself not in Object.prototype that maybe means arr cannot approach to the .keys() method?) What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You actually found another method, namely [`Array.prototype.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys)